# Position SVG Path to overlap relative canvas

Tags: canvas, svg, gxt

Using Sencha GXT I have drawn Scatter and line charts. Both are on the same surface, but line and axis elements are drawn on SVG while scatter is drawn on Canvas.

Example:

```
<div style="z-index: 1">
    <svg version="1.1" width="1500" height="0" style="overflow: hidden; width: 1426px; height: 872px;">
        <!-- line path -->
        <path style="-webkit-tap-highlight-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0); z-index: 11; position: relative;" d="M50.015625,379.09090492081083 L1416,450.2708911321506 " 
        stroke-linecap="BUTT" stroke-linejoin="MITER" stroke-miterlimit="4" stroke="rgb(0, 0, 0)" stroke-width="1.3" fill="rgb(0,0,0)"></path>
    </svg>

    <!-- canvas contains scatter points -->
    <canvas width="1426" height="872" style="overflow-x: hidden; z-index: 1; position: relative; top: -877px; width: 1426px;"></canvas>
</div>
```

[image: Chart]

Note how the scatter points cover the line. That's my problem. How would you suggest I make line to be on top of the points? I've tried using z-index, but I don't know if it's possible to set z-index for path relative to outside element (like in the example, path->svg->canvas). The only solution I can think of is to draw line on the same canvas but I would have to rewrite some of the GXT classes which I am not too keen on doing.

Any suggestions?

Edit:

Chart is drawn using java GXT like so:

```
//gxt class com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.series.LineSeries;
LineSeries<> lineSeries = new LineSeries<>(); 

//chart here is com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.Chart
chart.addSeries(lineSeries);
chart.redrawChart();

CustomSeries<> scatter = new CustomSeries<>();
chart.addSeries(scatter);
chart.redrawChart();

//ScatterSeries here is com.sencha.gxt.chart.client.chart.series.ScatterSeries 
CustomSeries extends ScatterSeries {
    //ScatterSeries drawSeries method overriden to draw series on canvas instead of SVG as per default
    //Hence my problem
}
```

Comment: SVG elements such as path do not support z-index. Try z-index on the svg element or swap the order of the canvas and SVG elements in the markup.

Comment: What do you mean by swapping order? As in `<canvas/><svg></svg>` instead of `<svg></svg><canvas/>` ? I don't think that would make any difference since z-index on canvas places it above svg.

Comment: I mean't forget using z-index altogether and do it by element ordering.

Comment: Besides, I can set z-index to svg element but in that case SVG hides whole canvas. I need to make certain path (not whole svg) be on top of canvas, though I am starting to doubt if that's possible.

Comment: I don't see why the SVG would hide the whole canvas unless there's something about it that you haven't put in the question.

Comment: Edited a bit the question (added style to svg element). Position:relative and -top makes canvas go on top of the SVG, so I don't think DOM order would matter in this case. to be honest, I don't have much experience dealing with SVGs